# Create duplex TCP tunnel in Windows with netcat

Tags: windows, tunnel, netcat

I need to create a TCP tunnel in Windows, I tried by chaining netcat:

```
ncat -l 3333 | ncat 192.168.0.110 4015
```

This creates a single direction tunnel, though, as only the first netcat's STDOUT becomes the second netcat's STDIN, but the opposite is not true - the second netcat's STDOUT does not become the first netcat's STDIN.

Is there a way to make a duplex connection in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

`ncat -l 3333 --sh-exec "ncat 192.168.0.110 4015"`should do the trick, as explained in the documentation https://nmap.org/ncat/guide/ncat-tricks.html